# XSLT tokenize nodeset

Tags: xslt, tokenize

I'm trying to create a variable that stores the value of an input string (TypeInput) in  init cap form. This new variable will be used in different places in my stylesheet. I created a template that I call to convert the input string to init cap form. However, when I run the stylesheet, the resulting variable TypeInputInitCap shows up as NodeSet(1) in the debugger and doesn't output text in my output. Any ideas why? See sample below.

```
<xsl:variable name="TypeInputInitCap">
    <xsl:call-template name="ConvertToInitCapString">
        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="$TypeInput"></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>    
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template name="ConvertToInitCapString">
    <xsl:param name="str"></xsl:param>        
    <!-- Extract each component of the name delimited by . -->
    <xsl:variable name="TokenNodeSet">
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($str, '.')">
            <!-- Init cap each component -->
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(upper-case(substring(.,1,1)), lower-case(substring(.,2)))"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="$TokenNodeSet">
        <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
        <xsl:if test="not(last())">
            <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please give an example of the input (value of `str` parameter).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that the `$TokenNodeSet` variable contains just a single string, and so the second `for-each` just loops once.

What about doing this instead:

```
<xsl:template name="ConvertToInitCapString"> 
  <xsl:param name="str"></xsl:param>         
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($str, '\.')"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(upper-case(substring(.,1,1)), lower-case(substring(.,2)))"/> 
    <xsl:if test="not(last())"> 
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text> 
    </xsl:if> 
  </xsl:for-each>
```

**EDIT**

Fixed the `tokenize()` call above as suggested by LarsH in the comments

Comment: That's correct... the for-each will concatenate its results: "For each item in the input sequence, evaluating the sequence constructor produces a sequence of items ... These output sequences are concatenated" (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-for-each). The spec is a little ambiguous, but string results apparently do get concatenated into a single string, not into a sequence of strings. **However**, this doesn't account for the fact that the OP says he gets *no* output. He should get the whole string (with no `.` characters) as output.

Comment: @LarsH: yes, to have a sequence of string you would have to create an XML element encapsulating each string

Comment: @OP: The other main problem is the use of `'.'` as your tokenizing delimiter pattern. That 2nd argument is a regular expression, so `'.'` matches any character. If you change it to `'\.'`, MiMo's solution should work.

Comment: It is possible to have a sequence of strings that are not wrapped in XML elements; e.g. `tokenize()` returns that. But maybe you meant specifically as the result of an `xsl:for-each`.

Comment: Yes, indeed my problem was that I didn't escape the '.' character. After escaping it, now I get a concatenated string with the '.'.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace

```
<xsl:variable name="TokenNodeSet">
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($str, '.')">
        <!-- Init cap each component -->
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(upper-case(substring(.,1,1)), lower-case(substring(.,2)))"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

with

```
<xsl:variable name="TokenNodeSet" select="for $token in tokenize($str, '\.') return concat(upper-case(substring($token,1,1)), lower-case(substring($token,2)))" />
```

or better yet with

```
<xsl:variable name="TokenNodeSet" as="xs:string*" select="for $token in tokenize($str, '\.') return concat(upper-case(substring($token,1,1)), lower-case(substring($token,2)))" />
```

or finally as it is XSLT 2.0 where there are no nodesets I would rename the variable as e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="TokenSequence" as="xs:string*" select="for $token in tokenize($str, '\.') return concat(upper-case(substring($token,1,1)), lower-case(substring($token,2)))" />
```

Comment: That's an elegant and concise solution, to have everything in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help. The second part in my template was not necessary, so I'm now using this version, which works. It re-adds a '.' character between the tokens. (I didn't use the short version suggested in this thread because I will end up with an extra dot at the end if concatenated.):

```
<xsl:template name="ConvertToInitCapString">
    <xsl:param name="str" select="."></xsl:param>        
    <!-- Extract each component of the name delimited by . -->
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($str, '\.')">
        <!-- Init cap each component -->
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(upper-case(substring(.,1,1)), lower-case(substring(.,2)))"></xsl:value-of>                
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="'.'"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>                              
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Note that with XSLT 2.0 you could simply use `<xsl:value-of select="$TokenSequence" separator="."/>` or `<xsl:value-of select="string-join($TokenSequence, '.')"/>` with the variable in my answer. Or you could avoid the variable with `<xsl:value-of select="for $token in tokenize($str, '\.') return concat(upper-case(substring($token,1,1)), lower-case(substring($token,2)))" separator="."/>`